# People picker people from AD other domain

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

I have a problem with my SharePoint 2013 on premise set up. At this moment we have a SharePoint web application at "SHAREPOINT.DOMAIN2.COM". I've set up a User Profile Synchronisation correctly in this web application with domain "DOMAIN1.COM" where the Active Directory is located.

All users are synced and available in the User Profiles of the "SHAREPOINT.DOMAIN2.COM" environment(735 profiles synced).
When i want to give permissions on a site in SHAREPOINT.DOMAIN2.COM, the users that are synced using the User Profile Synchronisation cannot be found.

Is there something that need to be configured manually?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Davy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of trust and SharePoint version you use.

SP2010:
2-way Trusts are automatically recognized and users show up in people picker
1-way Trusts need further configuration (including credentials) per webapplication

SP2013:
regardless of the type of trust you need to configure it like in the PS2010 1-way trust scenario

This can be achieved through a STSADM command (yes it´s still not gone):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075(v=office.15).aspx
Or more elegantly and efficiently through PowerShell:
http://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/01/powershell-for-people-picker-properties/